# How would I target the bottom li on the left side of this page

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to push the dotted border up 10px so there a nice clean space between the image of
Graham Courtney – Venue Media Manager London 2012.

I can't seem to target it correctly at the moment I've got something like this

.mid-list:nth-child(2) li

website here = http://goo.gl/NgCXC

I'm not to sure How I use these though, any guidance would be great.

Thanks

Comment: The link for this question is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want this: `.mid-list > li { margin-top: 10px; }`

Comment: isn't that the first li, I need the second one targetting

Comment: You're targeting all `li`s directly under `.mid-list` with this.

Comment: How can I target just the second one Simon,

Comment: Does it make sense to only _"push the dotted border up 10px so there a nice clean space between the image of Graham Courtney – Venue Media Manager London 2012."_ but not having that spacing on the other, identical items?

Comment: You should dynamically put some new class to the last record and an give de 10px margin.

Comment: It's great how you get voted down by people who obviously don't understand the subject. OP if this answer was the actual solution for your problem, it would be nice if you'd mark it as such ;).